# (C++/Qt) thread runs too much

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

In the example program below, my intention was to print five of same numbers per second, but in actual runtime the numbers are printed too much, sometimes around 10 or so. What is the problem in my code?

```
QTextStream qout(stdout);

class my_thread : public QThread
{
public:
    int n;

    my_thread()
    {
        n = 0;
    }

    void run()
    {
        while(n < 10)
        {
            qout << n++ << endl;
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    enum { N_THREADS = 5 }; // N_THREADS = 2 with no problem...
    std::array<my_thread, N_THREADS> thread_array;
    for (std::array<my_thread, N_THREADS>::iterator it = thread_array.begin(); it != thread_array.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->start();
    }
    for (std::array<my_thread, N_THREADS>::iterator it = thread_array.begin(); it != thread_array.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->wait();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT

I found some interesting behaviour that my program runs just as expected when N_THREADS is 1 or 2; it starts going weird exactly from when N_THREADS equals 3 or more. Why is this so?

Comment: `sleep(1);` -> `sleep(200)`, Sleeping for 1 ms will print your 10 numbers in 0,01 seconds.

Comment: @Blacktempel QThread::sleep()'s argument is in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Alright then, my fault. Thought it was the standard function.

Comment: @Blacktempel the standard sleep() function also takes an argument in seconds ;^)  http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Could you give example of expected result?